# Seeking example problems solved using Automated Design Synthesis (ADS) algorithms

Tags: cad, modeling, simulation, optimal-control, kalman-filters

**Premises**. [Gary N. Vanderplaats](https://omniquest.com/remembering-dr-garret-n-gary-vanderplaats) and coworkers at the Naval Postgraduate School in Monterey, California developed the **Automated Design Synthesis** (ADS) algorithms (software) that have been adapted to conform with [FortranCalculus](https://goal-driven.net/apps/fc-compiler.html) (FC).  The solvers are called APOLLO, ATLAS, ODIN, HELIOS, CRONUS, DEMETER, and CERES in FC.

I'm the author of a [Casebook](https://goal-driven.net/textbooks/) that show how to solve Engineering & Science (math) problems using 10+ solvers that are in the FC library.  But I need some example problems solved using one or more ADS solvers.  If you have one, please list the equations and/or output file.  How could I reference you in my Casebook?

**Question**. I'm seeking problems along the line of ODEs, implicit, constrained, boundary value problems (BVPs), Laplace equations, etc. Have such a problem **from industry** to share?

The following code shows an example problem that I'm seeking:

```
C ... Constrained Optimization example
   problem simple
     x = -1:   y = 0        ! Initial estimates
     **find** x, y while **holding** ‘g’ AND **matching** ‘h’  to **minimize** ‘f’
   end
   model modf       !  These equations are what I'm seeking
     g = 1 - (x**2) / 4 - y**2      !  'Holding' 'g' equations ... g > 0
     h = exp(x*y) - x - 2           !  'Matching' 'h' equations ... h = 0
     f = (x - 2)**2 + (y - 1)**2    !  'Minimize' 'f' equations
   end
```

Comment: What is the output of that script?

Comment: Welcome to Engineering SE! Please visit the [tour] page if you have not done so already. This question (asking for a list of items) is probably not suited for this SE [1](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [2](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).